# LibGDX not drawing image? [OS X]

Tags: java

I'm trying to draw an image, but I'm having problems. Here's the code:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    splash.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}


@Override
public void show() {
    Texture splashTexture = new Texture("/img/intrologo.png");
    splash = new Sprite(splashTexture);
    splash.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
}
```

I'm trying to run it on the desktop. The window runs! But I get a lot of errors in the console. Here they are:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: assets/img/intrologo.png
   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: assets/img/intrologo.png
   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:175)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.create(Texture.java:159)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:133)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:122)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:118)
   at com.eamonn.blackpoint2.screens.splash.show(splash.java:32)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
   at com.eamonn.blackpoint2.Blackpoint2.create(Blackpoint2.java:12)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:127)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: assets/img/intrologo.png (Internal)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:127)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.length(FileHandle.java:580)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:215)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
   ... 11 more
```

I asked this on the forums for LibGDX but after a few days I got no replies on help. It's like it's purposely being ignored.

The file 'intrologo.png' defiantly exists, it actually shows up in eclipse!

I also can't close the window. I have to force quit the window and it get's on my nerves :(

Thanks! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like it can't find the intrologo. Are you sure `assets/img/intrologo.png` is the correct filepath?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://gameprogrammerdesigner.blogspot.com/2011/11/make-game-libgdx-architecture.html) shows a simple setup for rendering a graphic.

1. When you initialize the Texture splashTexture, usually with libGDX you keep the assets in an assets folder named "data." Try initializing it to:

   Texture splashTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/intrologo.png"));
2. You need to call the draw method on the batch, and pass the texture to it along with an x and a y coordinate to draw the texture to.

   batch.begin();

   batch.draw(splashTexture, 50, 100);

   batch.end();

Play with the x and y coordinates to taste.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
Texture splashTexture = new Texture("/img/intrologo.png");
```

To This

```
Texture splashTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/intrologo.png"));
```

When creating texture it needs file not a pathname.
See : http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html

In Assets folder it should be like

```
assets
|_img
 |_intrologo.png
```